# Prove that $\sin(x)$ is locally invertible, whereas $\tan(x)$ is globally invertible on its domain

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing, inverse-function

Here's what I did for the proof that $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is locally invertible: since $y=\sin^{-1}x$ is the inverse of $y=\sin x, y=\sin^{-1}x\iff \sin(y)=x$.

But, since $y=\sin(x)$ is not one-to-one, its domain must be restricted to $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Now, how do I prove that $g(x)=\tan(x)$ is globally invertible in its domain? Also, why we choose $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ as the interval of restriction to get $y=\sin^{-1}(x)$? Why couldn't it be $[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3}{2}\pi]$?

**Edit:** the exercise requires me to prove that $g(x)=\tan(x)$ is globally invertible on its domain (maybe it's a typo).

**Edit:** Corrected interval.

Comment: Since $\tan(0)=\tan(\pi)$, I don't understand how is it that you expect to prove that the tangent function is globally invertible on its domain.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what's the difference **for you** between "local" and "globally" in this case. In my opinion, both functions are *locally* invertible as none of them is injective in its whole definition domain...

Comment: It would seem that neither function is globally invertible since they are both periodic.

Comment: @DonAntonio Why do we choose $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ as the interval to get $y=sin^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: @Kevin Because on that interval sine is bijective on $\;[-1,1]\;$ and thus invertible...just as we usually choose $\;\left(-\frac\pi2,\,\frac\pi2\right)\;$ for the tangent function for the same reason!

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, I meant for the interval $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\pi]$

Comment: @Kevin That's completely irrelevant: for sine it can $\;\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]\,,\,\,\left[-\frac{5\pi}2,\,-\frac{3\pi}2\right]\;$ ...and the same is true (with open intervals) for the tangent function...

Comment: @DonAntonio I see, thank you!

Comment: It seems a bit circular to me to be asked to prove the $\sin$ is locally invertible, then prove it by stating that it has an inverse function without any clarification or justification for the existence.

Comment: More properly: the sine function is not everywhere locally invertible: it isn't in a neighborhood of $(\pi/2,1)$, for instance; on the contrary the tangent function is locally invertible at every point of its graph. Neither function is globally invertible, because neither is injective.